# jQuery ajax json request not working over mobile network

Tags: android, json, jquery, mobile, servicestack

Ive been scratching my head with this for a few days now.

I have written a mobile specific website using plain old html and jquery.

It used ajax with json responses to get data from a service written using service stack.

all works perfectly fine from desktop and lots of different mobile i have tried (android, iphone, bb etc)

However there seems to be a specific issue with my handset (Samsung Galaxy S2 on vodafone)

When the handset is on wifi the ajax works perfectly and the json object is received from the service and processed correctly.

However when on mobile data the response does not come back as json but as the service stack web page (it looks like its not being told to return json correctly)

Im wondering if the headers could be being stripped out by vodafone or someting?

this is the ajax call being used

```
$.ajax({
            url: sgee.ApiUrl + "/api/GetRegionId/" + sgee.App.postcode,
            type: 'GET',
            dataTye: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    sgee.App.EnquiryId = data.enquiryId;
                    sgee.App.RegionId = data.regionId;
                    sgee.App.RegionName = data.regionName;
                    $("#regionTxt").html("We have identified that you live in the " + sgee.App.RegionName + " supply region.");
                    sgee.EndLoading(250);
                    sgee.HideStep(2);
                } else {
                    sgee.SetValidationError("#pcodeControl", "Please enter a valid UK postcode");
                }

            },
            error: function () {
                sgee.SetValidationError("#pcodeControl", "Please enter a valid UK postcode");
                sgee.SendError("Error on /api/GetRegionId/", "sgee.Step1");
            },
            complete: function () {

            }
        });
```

This is the data expected

```
{"postCode":"s63","regionId":14,"regionName":"YORKSHIRE","enquiryId":578106,"success":true,"returnedId":0}
```

and when running on mobile this is what i am receiving (ill not include the whole as it is long but it is just the html response as if i hadnt set the response type or browsed to the page)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<title>GetRegionId Snapshot of 03/08/2012 13:59:50</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

This really is driving me mad as it is impossible to debug (at least i cant find a way) i am using the android chrome remote developer tools to step through code but i cant capture the http request and response as it is on the mobile network.

Comment: What is the `Accept` HTTP Header when calling from mobile data?

Comment: Capture the actual request as received by the server (use wireshark or similar).  Post the request.  I ak curious why your server returns an HTML page.  Maybe the request is different in a significant way.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have reports from testers with different network provider than me telling me similar issues. I suspect the proxy servers of the network provider to do stuff they shouldn't do (these proxies are the same reason you can't use websockets on mobile network).

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing... But you're expecting json content right? If so, why is your response "text/html" instead of "application/json"?

Comment: the question isnt that it doesnt work full stop. but is why doesnt it work specifically on my phone only when connected to mobile data but works perfectly when connected to wifi.

Comment: its my guess that something on the mobile data network (either on the phone itself or in transport on the network - ie with vodafone) is changing the request somewhere along the line and the server isnt being told to respond in json anymore. however on different handsets and networks it works fine......

Comment: That could be strange anyway... It meant your request has been changed by "something" before reaching the server you're sending the request itself. Please, can you post the request?

Comment: Nope never got to the end of it. Changed company now so not had a chance to go back to it since.... Was a very strange one tho. Let me know if you do get to the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in there... "dataTye: 'json',". Could this be it?

Answer (score 0):

I think is due to type of form submission. use post instead of get...